# How to store indexed data in Asyncstorage

Tags: javascript, react-native, asyncstorage

I'm trying to use Asyncstorage in order to save and display different information. In my case, I would like to save a car name that the user sets then retrieve it.

The thing is, I can only store one value in Asyncstorage. So when I use :

```
 AsyncStorage.setItem('CARNAME',this.state.CarName)
```

It erases the last value that was stored.

How can I do it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use array and push the names into the array.

```
state = {
  cars: [],
}
```

Then push a car name

```
addCar = () => {
 this.setState({
   cars: [...this.state.cars, this.state.CarName]
 })
```

To save the array use JSON.stringify

```
AsyncStorage.setItem('CARS', JSON.stringify(this.state.cars))
```

To retrieve the list use JSON.parse.

```
const cars = await AsyncStorage.getItem('CARS');
console.log(JSON.parse(cars))
```